# Show same dialog twice in nested tab structure

Tags: mfc, hwnd, cwnd

In a nested tab structure of type `CMFCTabCtrl`(e.g. `CMFCTabCtrl` as Tab in parent `CMFCTabCtrl`), how can I show a parents tab inside the parent tab and a child `CMFCTabCtrl` tab?

*ParentTab1* **ParentTab2** *ParentTab3* <-- PARENT `CMFCTabCtrl`tabs
*ChildTab1* *ChildTab2* **ParentTab2** <-- *ParentTab3*/"Child" `CMFCTabCtrl`tabs

My first approach was basically to completely ignore that I have now "2" parents for the dialog displayed inside **ParentTab2**, but I get into all sort of graphical problems. How would I overcome this need for 2 parents? Can I create some sort of soft copy in order to show **ParentTab2** also inside the child `CMFCTabCtrl` and still keep both views responsible for click events etc.?

Comment: A window can have zero or one parents. If you need the same dialog template to show up in more than one place, you're going to have to create multiple instances of it.

Comment: Is there a way to create a deep copy of the dialog, such that I can create another instance once I receive a base CWND or HWND from the dialog?

Comment: Neither the generic `CWnd` type nor a plain `HWND` store enough type information to know which dialog template (if any) they were created from. If you need to create a new instance, you're going to have capture or recover that information some other way.

Comment: So there is no way to show one `CWnd` based instance in a parent and a child tab simultaneously?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? What is th4 context of needing such functionality? Sounds more like a property sheet with the same page added more than once to me ...

Comment: I have an existing CTabCtrl (Parent) and I need to combine two tabs into one new tab. The requirement is to keep the original tabs inside the parent but to additonally have them beeing tabed in the new tab. So I introduced a new CMFCTabCtrl (Child) as a tab and added these two tabs from the parent. But doing so I always loose the tabs inside the child once I loose focus, etc (They switch back to the parents original tab). So I was thinking that I have a problem considering that my child's tabs have the original CTabCtrl as parent and not my newly introduced CMFCTabCtrl. Hope this helps.